# Multithreading: How to manage MVC Action that calls a DLL that all sessions mistakenly have access to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, activereports

I have an ActiveReports [ActiveReports version 8, .Net] DLL that my code calls in a `Preview` action of my `Print` controller.  For some reason when users access it at the same time (from different sessions, of course), the data gets mangled and they see each other's data or lack of data.

```
    public ActionResult Preview(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            string reportInfo = null;
            ....
            MyARNamespace.ActiveReportsClass report = new MyARNamespace.ActiveReportsClass();
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    reportInfo = report.RunReport(parameters, stream);
                    if (stream.Length != 0)
                    {
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        byte[] pdf = stream.ToArray();
                        return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return HttpNotFound(reportInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return HttpNotFound("Error Generating PDF. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
```

I understand how to create a basic lock object and I'm guessing I have to implement some kind of locking mechanism to make sure each user has exclusive access to the thread.  I don't want subsequent users to fail, but they can wait.  What would be the best way to queue them, or would it be too much work to get ASP.Net to create separate worker processes for each user accessing the Action?

This may not be important, but when ASP.Net instantiates the ActiveReports DLL (which I did not write), it seems to be thrown in an apartment of sorts where it has its own path like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\19dc8c21\abb33c14\assembly\dl3\d826c723\5cea6a5c_62d8cf01`. I'm guessing each time it is concurrently accessed, ASP.Net is NOT creating a new instance of the DLL and a new apartment for a new thread for it to run in for each user/session.

Comment: Using a `lock` *will* queue them (though not necessarily FIFO). Unless the work being done is a lot (in which case you may want to implement polling so users don't timeout), then you can quite simply use a lock.

Comment: I looked into it a bit deeper and it looks like you are right about the queuing! FIFO isn't a big deal either. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You surely want to use lock in this case. A lock with a timeout would be a good choice.